# MySQL Join + "WHERE something=MAX(something)"

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a couple of tables that need to be be joined. The tables are:

**players**

- first_name
- last_name
- gender
- location_id
- *(additional irrelevant columns)*

and

**score_entries**

- score
- datetime
- player_id
- *(additional irrelevant columns)*

I need to join them based on `player_id` and only want to select records where the `players.location_id` is the greatest. So something like this:

```
SELECT
players.first_name,
players.last_name,
players.gender,
score_entries.score,
score_entries.datetime as jump_date
players.location_id,
FROM score_entries
LEFT JOIN players
ON score_entries.player_id = players.id
WHERE gender="m"
AND location_id="***(ONLY THE HIGHEST LOCATION_ID VALUE IN THE TABLE)***"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following query

```
SELECT 
    players.first_name, 
    players.last_name, 
    players.gender, 
    score_entries.score, 
    score_entries.datetime as jump_date, 
    players.location_id
FROM score_entries 
LEFT JOIN players 
ON score_entries.player_id = players.id 
WHERE gender="m" 
AND players.location_id = (SELECT MAX(location_id) from players)
```